# Can't load image from public folder with NextJS new "next/image"

Tags: next.js

With the old "next/image" - now "next/legacy/image" - I can load an image like this:

```
import Image from "next/legacy/image";
...
<Image width={90} height={45} src="/images/logo.png" />
```

Which will load the image from my `public` folder.

Changing to the new component, i.e.

```
import Image from "next/image";
...
<Image width={90} height={45} src="/images/logo.png" />
```

The image no longer loads. Is there something I need to change about the `src` to work with the new image component?

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to double check, is your `logo.png` image located inside `public/images` folder?

Comment: Sorry, yes it is